# How to generate schema from json and use it in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark

I need to install a package on spark-shell using  `spark-shell --packages "org.zalando:spark-json-schema_2.11:0.6.1"`

I am getting this error ( on Windows )  ->
`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`.

Spark-shell when tried alone invokes but not when I try with `--package` option. What seems to be the problem ?  If this works then I will try to convert a complex Json schema to dataframe schema (as suggested in [How to create DataFrame Schema from Json schem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417472/how-to-create-dataframe-schema-from-json-schem-file)) . I tried other option of generating the schema from dataframe and then assigning it to a variable and then using the variable as schema while reading json file. It didn't work.

Comment: is the package available in central maven repo?. Spark only checks in mvn central repo, to make spark search other mvn repos it needs to be configured using --repositories(https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment)

Comment: Ok....By the way I was able to figure out a way to derive the schema from the Json schema....here are the steps -  (1) df_new = sqlContext.read.json('s3a://2019/08/16/abc_schema.json', multiLine=True)   .....note the multiline option ....without that it doesn't work (2) new_schema=df_new.schema.json() (3) import json (4) new_schema1 = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(new_schema)) ......Then use new_schema1 to read the data file and form the dataframe.